# Zip file not getting generated

Tags: java, fileoutputstream, opencsv, zipoutputstream

I have this method in my springboot application which is generating 3 CSV files (related to Employee, Customer and Building) inside custom_users directory with timestamp appended to its name as shown below.
Right now it's only generating two CSV files (company and building related) because I am testing zip file related conversion for `employee_custom_file` as shown below.

Could anyone tell me what am I doing wrong while converting employee related content to zip file using `CSVWriter` (from `opencsv`)? I was expecting one zip file to show up with 2 other CSV files but for some reason, only 2 CSV files are generating.

Basically this part in the code below isn't working as I expected:

```
ZipEntry entry = new ZipEntry(file.getFileName().toString());
zos.putNextEntry(entry);
try {
    CSVWriter writer = new CSVWriter( new OutputStreamWriter(zos,StandardCharsets.UTF_8)))) {
        writer.writeAll(rsDemo, true);
    }
```

=====================================================================

```
public void sendMessage(String msg) throws DaoException {

        DataSource ds = null;
        Connection conn = null;
        PreparedStatement pstmt = null;
        PreparedStatement pstmtEmployee = null;
        PreparedStatement pstmtCompany = null; 
        PreparedStatement pstmBuilding = null; 

        ResultSet rs = null;
        ResultSet rsDemo = null;
        ResultSet rsCompany = null;
        ResultSet rsBuildings = null;


         String[] parts = msg.split("#");
         String requestID = parts[0].trim();
         String userName = parts[1].trim();
         String applicationName = parts[2].trim();

        logger.info("Request ID "+requestID);
        logger.info("User Name "+userName);
        logger.info("Application Name "+applicationName);



         try {

                ds = jdbcTemplate.getDataSource();
                conn = ds.getConnection();  

                /*===========================================================================*/
                /*    Code to generate a employee CSV file              */ 
                /*===========================================================================*/
                pstmtEmployee = conn.prepareStatement(getPatientEmployeeSQL);
                pstmtEmployee.setString(1, requestID);
                rsDemo = pstmtEmployee.executeQuery();

                ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rsDemo.getMetaData();

                 FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("your_files.zip");
                 BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fos);
                 ZipOutputStream zos = new ZipOutputStream(bos);

                 Path dir = Paths.get("/srv/custom_users", userName);
                 Files.createDirectories(dir);

                 Path file = dir.resolve("employee_custom_file" + unixTimestamp + ".csv");
                 /*try (CSVWriter writer = new CSVWriter(Files.newBufferedWriter(file))) {
                     writer.writeAll(rsDemo, true);
                 }*/
                 ZipEntry entry = new ZipEntry(file.getFileName().toString());
                 zos.putNextEntry(entry);
                 try (CSVWriter writer = new CSVWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(zos,StandardCharsets.UTF_8)))) {
                     writer.writeAll(rsDemo, true);
                 }


                 logger.info("Employee File Generated");



                 /*===========================================================================*/
                 /*    Code to generate a company CSV file                                      */ 
                 /*===========================================================================*/

                pstmtCompany = conn.prepareStatement(getCompanySQL);
                pstmtCompany.setString(1, requestID);
                rsCompany = pstmtCompany.executeQuery();

                ResultSetMetaData rsmdFacts = rsCompany.getMetaData();


                 Path filecompany = dir.resolve("company_custom_file_" + unixTimestamp + ".csv");
                 try (CSVWriter writer = new CSVWriter(Files.newBufferedWriter(filecompany))) {
                     writer.writeAll(rsCompany, true);
                 }

                 logger.info("Company CSV File Generated");


                 /*===========================================================================*/
                 /*    Code to generate a building CSV file                                 */ 
                 /*===========================================================================*/

                 pstmBuilding = conn.prepareStatement(getBuildingSQL);
                  pstmBuilding.setString(1, requestID);
                  rsBuildings = pstmBuilding.executeQuery();

                   ResultSetMetaData rsmdBuildings = rsBuildings.getMetaData();


                    Path fileBuildings = dir.resolve("building_custom_file_" + unixTimestamp + ".csv");
                     try (CSVWriter writer = new CSVWriter(Files.newBufferedWriter(fileBuildings))) {
                         writer.writeAll(rsBuildings, true);
                     }

                    logger.info("Buildings CSV File Generated");




                }
            catch(Throwable th) {
                throw new DaoException(th.getMessage(), th);
            }
            finally {
                //resource Closing statements

            }   



    }
```

Comment: I believe `ZipOutputStream` should not be used to constantly write to it. Finish writing the file and zip it afterwards

Comment: Thanks but I don't want to write the file to the disk and then zip. Basically, I'm trying to zip the csv contents on the fly.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating a zip on the fly with csv files inside](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16905599/creating-a-zip-on-the-fly-with-csv-files-inside)

Comment: Yeah, I've seen that post but trying to figure out what exact problem I'm facing in my code above.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a call to `closeEntry` which is omitted from the code example?

Note that writes to the zip output stream are to whatever backs the output stream.  'Writing' the entry writes to the zip stream, and not to disk, unless that is how the output stream was set up.

From `ZipOutputStream`:

```
/**
 * Closes the current ZIP entry and positions the stream for writing
 * the next entry.
 * @exception ZipException if a ZIP format error has occurred
 * @exception IOException if an I/O error has occurred
 */
public void closeEntry() throws IOException {
```

Comment: I haven't called `closeEntry` as of yet. I'm just trying to get one zip file generated for my testing purpose. Please suggest when and where should I call if that needs to happen for my testing purpose?

Comment: After writing all data for a single entry, put in a call to 'closeEntry' to finish up the write of the entry.  Based on the code example, if 'writeAll' writes all of the data intended for the entry, just after 'writeAll' would be where to put in the call.

Comment: So I added these two lines `writer.flush();zos.closeEntry();`, just below this line `writer.writeAll(rsDemo, true);` and still it's not generating a zip file.

Comment: The other piece of the API is calling 'finish()' on the zip output stream after all entries have been written.  (And finally, calling 'close' on the zip output stream.)

Comment: As a testing alternative, you could try writing to a non-zip type output stream, and see if that successfully transfers the data.  That would separate any problems with the zip API usage from the transfer steps.

Comment: Thanks. I tried this non-zip alternative which is commented in my code above `try (CSVWriter writer = new CSVWriter(Files.newBufferedWriter(file))) {
            writer.writeAll(rsDemo, true);
        }` and everything works fine. It's the zip thing creating issues :(

Answer (score 0):

I got it working. My this line of code `FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("your_files.zip");` was creating problem as I wasn't using my `dir` variable anywhere. Hence I had to use it like this to make it work:

```
OutputStream fos = Files.newOutputStream(dir.resolve("your_files.zip"));
BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fos);
ZipOutputStream zos = new ZipOutputStream(bos);
```