# How to return a zip file stream using Java Springboot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I use Springboot, I want to generate zip file and then return to frontend.

```java
@PostMapping(value="/export", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<ZipOutputStream> export() {
    // customService.generateZipStream() is a service method that can 
    //generate zip file using ZipOutputStream and then return this stream
    ZipOutputStream zipOut = customService.generateZipStream();
    return ResponseEntity
                  .ok()
                  .header("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=export.zip")
                  .header("Content-Type","application/octet-stream")
                  .body(zipOut)
}
```

The zip file can be generated correctly(in local dir) but I got **below error** when return stream to frontend:

```
spring.HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException: Could not find acceptable representation
```

Then i checked in google and changed return type to `ResponseEntity<StreamResponseBody>`, but how should I change `ZipOutputStream` to `StreamResponseBody` in method `body(...)`, the solution in google is create zip output stream within `body()` method like that:

```java
   // pseudocode
   .body(out -> { 
                   ZipOutputStream zipOut = new ZipOutputStream(out));
                   zipOut.putEntry(...);
                   zipOut.write(...);
                   zipOut.closeEntry();
                   ... balabala
                }
```

**My question** is how to use `StreamResponseBody` in this scenario **or** any alternative solution to return a zip stream that might a little large.

Comment: Your last pseudo code block looks good, what is the problem with it?

Comment: @Robert, I have solved this issue, will share my code using  this pseudo code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for everyone's help, I checked yours answers and solved this issue by updating export logic.

**My solution:**

Re-define method as `customService.generateZipStream(ZipOutputStream zipOut)`so that I can create a zip stream with `StreamResponseBody` in **controller** layer and then send it to **service** layer, in service layer, i will do export.

presudo code as below:

```java
@PostMapping(value="/export", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity< StreamResponseBody > export() {
    // customService.generateZipStream() is a service method that can 
    //generate zip file using ZipOutputStream and then return this stream
    
    return ResponseEntity
                  .ok()
                  .header("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=export.zip")
                  .body(outputStream -> {
                     // Use inner implement and set StreamResponseBody to ZipOutputStream
                     try(ZipOutputStream zipOut = new ZipOutputStream(outputStream)) {
                         customService.generateZipStream(zipOut);
                     }
                  });
}
```

`customService` presudo code:

```java
public void generateZipStream(ZipOutputStream zipOut) {
    // ... do export here
    zipOut.putEntry(...);
    zipOut.write(...);
    zipOut.closeEntry();
    // ... balabala

}
```

**Hope** it can help you if you have similar question.

Answer (score 4):

If you are using **Spring 3**, you can use a lot of the **swagger** annotation interfaces to help cleanly build your `ResponseEntity` while using the `StreamingResponseBody` to properly prototype the format to be expected by spring.

The `body` code here is a shortened way of mapping the `ZipOutputStream` stream into `StreamingResponseBody` type that the controller expects to return (`.body(out -> {...})` does this in my code below).

The *[controller]* code would look like this:

```java
    @GetMapping(value = "/myZip")
    @Operation(
        summary = "Retrieves a ZIP file from the system given a proper request ID.",
        responses = {
            @ApiResponse(
                description = "Get ZIP file containing data for the ID.",
                responseCode = "200",
                content = @Content(schema = @Schema(implementation = StreamingResponseBody.class))),
            @ApiResponse(
                description = "Unauthenticated",
                responseCode = "401",
                content = @Content(schema = @Schema(implementation = ApiErrorResponse.class))),
            @ApiResponse(
                description = "Forbidden. Access Denied.",
                responseCode = "403",
                content = @Content(schema = @Schema(implementation = ApiErrorResponse.class)))
        })
    public ResponseEntity<StreamingResponseBody> myZipBuilder(@RequestParam String id, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws IOException {
        final String fileName = "MyRequest_" + id + "_" + new SimpleDateFormat("MMddyyyy").format(new Date());

        return ResponseEntity.ok()
            .header(CONTENT_DISPOSITION,"attachment;filename=\"" + fileName + ".zip\"")
            .contentType(MediaType.valueOf("application/zip"))
            .body(out -> myZipService.build(id, response.getOutputStream()));
    }
```

The code for your service `build` method simply needs to take in the whatever parms you need for the data, **plus** your `ServletOutputStream responseOutputStream` parm to allow you to build your `ZipOutputStream` object seeded by that stream.

In my little example below, you can see I build some CSV data in the `buildDataLists` method (not shown), which is just a List of List<String[]>.. I then take each of the top level List items and push them into the `ZipOutputStream` object using my `streamWriteCsvToZip`.  The point is, you build your ZIP stream seeded with the responseOutputStream you were given from the controller. Once you have built your zip fully, make sure to close it up (in my case `zos.close()`). Then return the `zos` object to the controller.

```java
    /**
     * Get ZIP file containing datafiles for a given request id
     *
     * @param id of the request
     * @param responseOutputStream for streaming the zip results
     * @return ZipOutputStream a ZIP file stream for the contents
     * @throws AccessDeniedException    if user does not have access to this function
     * @throws UnauthenticatedException if user is not authenticated
     */
    public ZipOutputStream build(String id, ServletOutputStream responseOutputStream) throws IOException {

        try {
            List<List<String[]>> csvFilesContents = buildDataLists(id);

            final ZipOutputStream zos = new ZipOutputStream(responseOutputStream);
            streamWriteCsvToZip("control", id, zos, csvFilesContents.remove(0));
            streamWriteCsvToZip("roles", id, zos, csvFilesContents.remove(0));
            streamWriteCsvToZip("accounts", id, zos, csvFilesContents.remove(0));

            zos.close(); // finally closing the ZipOutputStream to mark completion of ZIP file
            return zos;
        } catch (IOException | ClientException ex) {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
```

No magic here. Just take your data and put it into the zip stream. In my case, I was pulling list/array data, dropping it into a CSV, then putting that CSV in to the zip (as an entry by using `zos.putNextEntry(entry);`). Both the CSVs and the ZIP are kept as streams so that nothing is written to the filesystem during this operation, and the final result can be just streamed out by the controller. Make sure to close out the entry each time you write one to the zip output stream (`zos.closeEntry()`).

```java
    private void streamWriteCsvToZip(String csvName, String id, ZipOutputStream zos, List<String[]> csvFileContents)
        throws IOException {
        String filename = id + "_" + csvName + ".csv";
        ZipEntry entry = new ZipEntry(filename); // create a zip entry and add it to ZipOutputStream
        zos.putNextEntry(entry);

        CSVWriter csvWriter = new CSVWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(zos));  // Directly write bytes to the output stream
        csvWriter.writeAll(csvFileContents);  // write the contents
        csvWriter.flush(); // flush the writer
        zos.closeEntry(); // close the entry. Note: not closing the zos just yet as we need to add more files to our ZIP
    }
```

Comment: Is there anyway to notify the client of an error in the middle of the streaming/zipping process ? It seems entering in the catch block does NOT effect the response to indicate anything  other than closing the resources since the response already committed !!!!!!

In your example, say a failure in `roles` zipping somehow ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to send back it as a byte array:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

ZipOutputStream zipOut = customService.generateZipStream();

int count;
byte data[] = new byte[2048];
BufferedInputStream entryStream = new BufferedInputStream(is, 2048);
while ((count = entryStream.read(data, 0, 2048)) != -1) {
    zos.write( data, 0, count );
}
entryStream.close();

return ResponseEntity
              .ok()
              .header("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=export.zip")
              .header("Content-Type","application/octet-stream")
              .body(bos.toByteArray());
```

Consider that you will need to change the return type to `ResponseEntity<byte[]>`.

Comment: byte[] will stay in memory right? If so,memory will be very large even get OOM when a lot of requests come in.

Comment: It's a possible issue

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can return `ResponseEntity<Byte[]>`

https://github.com/wangwei-ying/initializr/blob/main/initializr-web/src/main/java/io/spring/initializr/web/controller/ProjectGenerationController.java

line: 126

Comment: Same to @Lorelorelore answer, it may cost a lot of memory during export.