# java does not create and download my zip file

Tags: java, spring, model-view-controller, zip

I am trying to make a zip file of a select number of files and have it download. Here is my code. Currently it runs without any errors but nothing happens: I expect a zip file to start downloading.

```
    @RequestMapping(value="/downloadQuestion", produces="application/zip") 
    public ResponseEntity<?>  zipFolder(HttpServletResponse response, @RequestParam("assnname") String assnname,
        @RequestParam("question") String question, @RequestParam("fileList") String[] fileList) throws IOException {

        if (question.equals("") || assnname.equals("")) {
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST).build();
        }

        response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
        response.addHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"test.zip\"");
        response.setContentType("application/zip");

        ZipOutputStream zipOutputStream = new ZipOutputStream(response.getOutputStream());
        CustomUserDetails currentUser = (CustomUserDetails)SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();

        String questionDirectory = currentUser.getDirectorypath()+"/"+assnname+"/"+question;
        
        if (fileList == null) {
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT).build();
        }

        List<File> files = new ArrayList<File>();
        for (int i = 0; i<fileList.length; i++) {
            files.add(new File(questionDirectory+"/"+fileList[i]));
        }

        for (File file : files) {
            try {
                zipOutputStream.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry(file.getName()));

                FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(file);

                IOUtils.copy(fileInputStream, zipOutputStream);

                fileInputStream.close();
                zipOutputStream.closeEntry();
            } catch (Exception e) {
               
            }
        }

        zipOutputStream.close();
        return ResponseEntity.ok("Assignment zipped successfully");
    }
```

update: my code now looks like this. i step through it and everything works as expected i just do not get a zip file download.

```
@RequestMapping(value="/downloadQuestion", produces="application/zip", method = { RequestMethod.GET, RequestMethod.POST })
    public ResponseEntity<StreamingResponseBody> zipFiles(@AuthenticationPrincipal CustomUserDetails user, @RequestParam("fileList") String[] fileList, @RequestParam("assnname") String assnname, @RequestParam("question") String question) {
        return ResponseEntity
                .ok()
                .header("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\""+assnname+".zip\"")
                .body(out -> {
                    var zipOutputStream = new ZipOutputStream(out);

                    ArrayList<File> files = new ArrayList<File>();

                    String questionDirectory = user.getDirectorypath()+"/"+assnname+"/"+question;

                    for ( int i = 0; i < fileList.length; i++) {
                        files.add(new File(questionDirectory+"/"+fileList[i]));
                    }

                    for (File file : files) {
                  
                        zipOutputStream.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry(file.getName()));
                        FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(file);

                        IOUtils.copy(fileInputStream, zipOutputStream);

                        fileInputStream.close();
                        zipOutputStream.closeEntry();
                    }

                    zipOutputStream.finish();
                    zipOutputStream.close();
                });
    }
```

and on the javascript side, we have:

```
                    let textboxFormData = new FormData();

                    textboxFormData.append("assnname", document.getElementById("chosenassn").value);
                    textboxFormData.append("question", document.getElementById("selectQuestionDropdown").value);


                    var options = await response.text();
                    options = options.replace("[","");
                    options = options.replace("]","");
                    options = options.replace("\"","");

                    options = options.replace(/["']/g, "");
                    const optionsArray = options.split(",");
                    textboxFormData.append("fileList", optionsArray);

                    let responseDownload = await fetch('/hiking/downloadQuestion', {
                        method: "POST",
                        body: textboxFormData
                    });
```

Comment: `catch (Exception e) { }` ← **Never do that.**  If something is going wrong, you do not want your method to act as if everything is okay!  Remove the try/catch and add ZipException to the `throws` clause in your method declaration.

Comment: thank you. fixed that now, but the issue remains that im not getting a zip file.

Comment: I suspect mixing ResponseEntity and direct manipulation of the HttpServletResponse may be a factor.  `ResponseEntity.ok("Assignment zipped successfully")` creates a response whose body is a String.  You can only have one response body;  either the body is the zip file or the body is that String.  I’m not sure what the preferred Spring approach would be;  I personally would make the method’s return type void, and would use `response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_NO_CONTENT);` instead of returning ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT).build().

Comment: thank you. i did as you said but it still did not produce a zip file

Comment: What happens when you try to download a zip file?  How are you downloading it?  Are you using a web browser?

Comment: i expect that hitting that endpoint will produce a zip file with this code. nothing happens instead.

Comment: How are you “hitting that endpoint”?  Are you typing a command?  Are you using a web browser?

Comment: using javascript, i go: ```let responseDownload = await fetch('/hiking/downloadQuestion', {
                        method: "POST",
                        body: textboxFormData
                    });``` where textboxFormData contains my list of files and a few other parametres

Comment: That is important information that should be in your question.  Also, you should add a “javascript” tag to your question.

Answer (score 0):

In the first code snippet, you just return the http response code, but no zip file in the body. [You can pass the body either as argument to the ok method or by using the explicit body() method.](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/ResponseEntity.html#ok())

So, either:

```
zipOutputStream.close();
return ResponseEntity
         .ok()
         .body(zipOutputStream);
```

or:

```
zipOutputStream.close();
return ResponseEntity
         .ok(zipOutputStream);
```

like in [these examples](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-controller-return-image-file)

In the second code snippet, you pass a lambda expression to the body() method. This does not work imho, because the lambda expression does not deliver a result value. As above, try passing the instance of the zipfile explicitly to the body() method.

Additionally, you must forward the zipOutputStream to the response outputStream, like this answer [suggests.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68298912/how-to-return-a-zip-file-stream-using-java-springboot)  The whole code would then look like this:

```
    @RequestMapping(value="/downloadQuestion", produces="application/zip", method = { RequestMethod.GET, RequestMethod.POST })
public ResponseEntity<?> zipFiles(@AuthenticationPrincipal CustomUserDetails user, @RequestParam("fileList") String[] fileList, @RequestParam("assnname") String assnname, @RequestParam("question") String question, HttpServletResponse response) {
    try {
        var zipOutputStream = new ZipOutputStream(response.getOutputStream());

        ArrayList<File> files = new ArrayList<>();

        String questionDirectory = user.getDirectorypath()+"/"+assnname+"/"+question;


        for (String s : fileList) {
            files.add(new File(questionDirectory + "/" + s));
        }

        for (File file : files) {

            zipOutputStream.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry(file.getName()));
            FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(file);

            IOUtils.copy(fileInputStream, zipOutputStream);

            fileInputStream.close();
            zipOutputStream.closeEntry();
        }

        zipOutputStream.finish();
        zipOutputStream.close();

        return ResponseEntity
                .ok()
                .header("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + assnname + ".zip\"")
                .body(zipOutputStream);
    }
    catch (IOException ioe) {
        return ResponseEntity.internalServerError()
                .body("Could not generate zip file");
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I did not have time to compile/build the code now. I hope the code snippets can be understood anyway.

Comment: when I try this I get ```body' has private access in 'org.springframework.http.HttpEntity'``` so I am not sure you can access body that way

Comment: I edited the code snippets. body is indeed private, if ok() receives body as an argument directly.

Comment: I tried your solution and I have gotten ```No converter for [class java.util.zip.ZipOutputStream] with preset Content-Type 'application/zip'``` any ideas for why that is happening?

Comment: it seems you cannot set a header with ResponseEntity.header either

Comment: The zipOutputStream must be streamed directly to the response object via getOutputStream(). I don't know yet why that is, must look into it. But I adjusted the code. Sorry that I did not have time to test the code fully yet, I just wanted to provide some hints. Hope that helps.

Comment: I verified the code now in the IDE and the current version does return a zip file to me.

Comment: when I try this code, I get an error that says ```org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException: No converter for [class java.util.zip.ZipOutputStream] with preset Content-Type 'null'```